# Only Primary Owner can post Message on Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a Slack App and Workspace. Since I am the admin, I can post the message to anyone and to any channel. But, when I am trying to post a message as a different user through an api call using the method chat.postMessage, it gives me the following response.

```
{"ok":false,"error":"missing_scope","needed":"chat:write:user","provided":"identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar,identity.team","warning":"missing_charset","response_metadata":{"warnings":["missing_charset"]}}
```

I checked the Oauth and Permissions page on Slack and I have the scope as chat:write:user.

I cannot figure out what to do here. Could the auth tokens of the users restricted to be not able to post message and if so , how can I permit them to post message.

I also tried to open a direct message channel usin im.open method from the Slack documentation however, it provides a reasponse as under:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"missing_scope","needed":"im:write","provided":"identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar,identity.team"}
```

Again, when I check I already have im.open in the scope/permissions.

One last thing that I tried was I made another user as an admin,but it still says the same.

I am attaching my GetAccessToken method here. I think I am requesting the scope in the wrong manner or something like that.

```
public SlackAuthToken GetAccessToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string code)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                string oAuthUrl = "https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + clientId + "&scope=im%3Aread+chat%3Awrite%3Auser";
                var authResponse = client.DownloadString(oAuthUrl);


                string url ="https://xxx.slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&code=" + code;
                var response = client.DownloadString(url);

                SlackAuthToken slackTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackAuthToken>(response);
                string accessToken = slackTest.AccessToken;
                string urlUserIdentity = "https://slack.com/api/users.identity?token=" + accessToken;
                var responseUser = client.DownloadString(urlUserIdentity);
                SlackAuthToken slack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackAuthToken>(responseUser);
                return slackTest;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the app in your workspace? Maybe the app requests the permissions now, but didn't do so at installation time in your workspace.

Comment: I did.Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: When you say "I checked the Oauth and Permissions page on Slack and I have the scope as chat:write:user." where exactly did you check? On api.slack.com or in the scopes included in your Slack Oauth button?

Comment: @Savageman On api.slack.com.

Comment: I got a response from Slack as follows: SIWS(Sign in with Slack) scopes cannot be combined with non-SIWS scopes in the same Oauth flow so users will need to be put through the Oauth flow for apps that have SIWS scopes twice: 1. First, with just the identity.* scopes and 2.Next, with nay of the non-SIWS scopes. But, I am failing to understand how to have two scopes. Do I add another api call for chat:write or add it somehow in the cshtml code for the button.