# Request scopes from Slack for messages

Tags: slack-api

i have a Slack app and until yesterday only the primary owner could send the message. I asked the Slack team on how to solve this issue to allow all users to be able to send messages on Slack. The answer was to first use the Sign in with Slack button to log them in. Then another button but with different scopes.

My question here is, I was able to send messages as users using the button as follows :

```
<input type="button" value="Authenticate again to send Message" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="location.href = 'https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=incoming-webhook,im:write,chat:write:user&client_id=xxyyzz'"/>
```

Now, I am trying to do the same extra scopes request in the background by displaying a view that says" Please wait"

Attaching the code below:

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "@Url.Action(MenuItem, "SetupSlack")",
            //data: { code: 'Model.Code' },
            data: { code: '@Model' },
            success: function(rsp) {
                window.location.replace(rsp.redirect);

            },
            error: function() {
                // Show error.
            }
        });
</script>
```

And the controller code is as follows:

```
 public ActionResult SetupSlack(string code)
        {
            SlackAuthToken slackToken = slackService.GetAccessToken( clientId, clientSecret, code);

            string redirectUrl;
            if (slackToken.IsAuthenticated && slackToken.HasWrite)
            {
                Alert("Slack setup successfully!!!!", AlertLevel.Success);
                redirectUrl = Url.Action(MenuItem, "Index");
            }
            else if (slackToken.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                redirectUrl = "https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=incoming-webhook,im:write,chat:write:user&client_id=aabbcc";

            }
            else
            {
                Alert("Slack setup failed. Please try again, if the problem persists please contact support.", AlertLevel.Success);
                redirectUrl = Url.Action(MenuItem, "Index");
            }
            return JsonNet(new { redirect = redirectUrl });
        }
```

It is not leading to the post message authentication page.Also, the other error that am getting it "code already used" as one of the responses in the OAuth flow.

Can anyone help me here.
I made the button work fine, but this should work as well.

Comment: This seams to be the third question you are asking on the same topic. Here are the others, all still open as of now: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365982/add-permissions-for-user-on-slack
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332569/only-primary-owner-can-post-message-on-slack

Comment: I would strongly recommend to stick with one question and update the original question if you did not get a good answer, or if have new information you like to add. We aim to resolve every question here on SO - for you benefit, but also for others that may have a similar issue.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I did not know that. I thought this was a different question as I am doing it differently now. I will keep that in mind in future.

Comment: Looks like this user was kicked from StackOverflow....

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to give a more complete answer to your problem as I understand it.

**Requirements**

1. You have a website and you want users from your Slack team to be able to send messages to Slack from it.
2. Messages must be sent on behalf of the user, not from the app

**Solution**

1. To authenticate and get the slack user ID users need to log into your website using "[Sign-in with Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack)"
2. When the user wants to send a message, your website checks its database for the access token belonging to the current user (the slack user ID is the key) and then uses that token to send a the slack message via API with [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)
3. If the website can not find a token for the current user in its database, the token needs to be created. For that the user is presented with a button that starts an [Oauth flow with Slack requesting the required permission](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth#flow)s (e.g. "Grant permissions to website"). After the token has been created it is stored in the database of the website, so this process has to be run once per user only. The user can then sent his message.

**Notes**

- The Oauth process in step 3 is basically the same as installing the Slack app for each individual user. It is called configurations. This only works though if the admins of your Slack team have granted all users the right to install this particular Slack app
- The Oauth process in step 3 and can NOT be run the background as you suggested in your question since it requires direct user interaction. It will always require the user to first login and then approve the requested permissions for your Slack app.

Comment: You got me right. I want to do step 1 of Oauth in the background though because step 3 surely does require user approval. In solution point 3, we have to authenticate twice right because first time user signs in he doesn't have permissions to post message and second time he is redirected to the step 1 of the oauth flow with different scopes such as im:write etc. and if he approves then he is ready to send the message. Both of these should occur only once.

Comment: Yes, you have to run through Oauth twice. But only once per user. The next time a user uses the website his  token is already there and he only needs to sign in.

Comment: Please understand thought that it is not possible to ran any of the two Oauth steps (1 & 2) in the background. Both require user interaction. So this is the best solution you get unless you drop requirement 2 and let the user send generic messages which will be coming from the app, not the user

Answer (score 0):

This can not work. The button is triggering the installation of your Slack app by a user via Oauth 2.0. By definition the Oauth process can not be run in the background, but requires the user to follow the redirect to the login-page from Slack and approve the permissions requested for your Slack app.

Comment: I am not using the button anymore for requesting extra scopes but I am using a button for Sign in with Slack. So you mean to say I need to have buttons in order to authenticate again for requesting other scopes? Right?

Comment: yes. you can not run the Oauth process in the background with AJAX, since it will always require user input.